# PHP: Highlight query and truncate after a (certain) word break and not character count

Tags: php, string, smarty, truncate

I have this PHP function:

```
function hilite($string)
{
    $term = $_GET['s'];
    if( $term ) {
        if( isset($GLOBALS['re_matches']) || preg_match_all('~("[^"]+"|\b\w+\b)~', $term, $GLOBALS['re_matches']) )
        {
            foreach( $GLOBALS['re_matches'][0] as $match )
            {
                $match = quotemeta(str_replace(array('+', '-', '*', '"', '(', ')'), '', $match));
                $string = preg_replace("/\b($match)\b/i", "<span class=\"hilite\">$1</span>", $string);
            }
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

and I'm using this in my smart template:

```
 {$text.title|mb_substr::0::82|htmlspecialchars|hilite}{if mb_strlen($text.title) > 82} ... {/if} 
 {$text.description|mb_substr::0::82|htmlspecialchars|hilite}{if mb_strlen($text.description) > 82} ... {/if}
```

It works well if I don't truncate this,

```
{$text.title|htmlspecialchars|hilite}  
{$text.description|htmlspecialchars|hilite}
```

but if I do, I have cases where truncate cuts right after where the highlighted query word is, so everything breaks.

My question is: what would be the easiest solution to avoid breaking a highlighted word if the highlighted word is the last and where it is broken by character count.

Thank you in advance.